# How to get my loop to start from the beginning after error detected

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get my loop to restart when it comes across an user input error. I need it to restart at the very beginning and not just the last question.

So below when it says validImput = false this is where I am trying to get it to restart.

```
{
var validInput = true;
var start = confirm('Add item to shoping cart');
if (start == true) {

    // ask first question
    var orderProductCodeArr = parseInt(prompt('Enter input: '), 10);

    if (isNaN(orderProductCodeArr)) {
        alert("input is not a valid number");
        validImput = false

    } else if (orderProductCodeArr < 0 || orderProductCodeArr >= PRODUCT_LIST.length) {
        alert("code does not match any item");
        validInput = false;
    }

    // ask second question

     else if(validInput == true) {
        var item = PRODUCT_LIST[orderProductCodeArr];
        alert("item is: " + item);
    }
        // get quantity input


    var quanityArr = parseInt (prompt('Enter quality amount'),10);
        if (isNaN(quanityArr)) {
        alert("input is not a valid number");
        validInput = false;

    }




} else {
    document.writeln('still to come')
}
```

}

Comment: You posted everything `except` that very loop:)

Comment: @hanky Panky See how I need help lol I thought that by surrounding everything in curly brackets, it made it part of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual method of starting something over is some sort of loop construct, often using `while` like this:

```
while (true) {
    // your loop code here

    // you can use break; to break out of the while loop 
    //     anywhere to stop repeating
    // you can use continue; to jump to the next iteration immediately

}
```

Or, sometimes you use a loop condition like this:

```
var doAgain = true;
while (doAgain) {

    // within the loop, you set doAgain to false when you are done
    // and don't want to repeat the loop again

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function test()
{

   for(var s=0;s<5;s++)
   {
    try
    { 

     //body of the for loop

    }catch(e){s=0;}
   }

}
```

Comment: @NidhishKrishnam If its not to much trouble could you explain to me what your code is doing.

Comment: inside the for loop if any exception occurs it will be catched and the loop starts from the begining

Comment: Probably a stupid question, and I am sorry if it is, but does the `function test()
{

   for(var s=0;s<5;s++)
   {
    try
    { 
`  go at the very top of what I have and does the `}catch(e){s=0;}
   }

}` go at the very bottom, or do I put this for each section ... Does that make sense? sorry if it doesn't

Comment: Yes only one loop but when I done that, it stopped it from working all together, the confirm box wouldn't come up.... so am doing something wrong.

Comment: are you sure there is any exception occurs in your loop

Comment: Whats above is exactly what is meant to be in the loop. I am not sure what you are asking me. Sorry